# Hard drive present, but inaccessible, Read error in testdisk, but does not appear in partimage

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

After a power surge, Windows 10 refused to boot: "No Operating System".

I'm using Systemresccd to boot and try to recover the data.

`fdisk -l` lists 2 disks, the systemresc boot USB (which is designated sda) and a flashdrive to which I plan to extract any recovered data (this drive is designated sdc).

sdb is obviously where the missing hard drive is, and this is confirmed when I type in `testdisk /dev/sdb` and it lists the drive as ST_M13FQBL.

It also identifies it as 4142 MB /3950 MiB - CHS 503 255 63

However, it just says Partition: Read error and ends with "No Partitions found".

Partimage gives the option to image from sda and sdc, but does not list sdb.

Is there anything else I could try? (Budget is tight).

Answer (score 1):

> "ST_M13FQBL"

This suggests a firmware issue. If it's limited to this firmware issue remains to be seen.

> Is there anything else I could try? (Budget is tight).

Better approach is: Ask if you can afford to lose the data? If not but current budget is tight, then put the drive aside and send the drive to a data recovery lab when budget permits. It is unlikely that waiting one year for example has an effect on recoverability.

Answer (score -3):

Check, if paltes rotating, when powering HDD. If not - open germetic cover and push plates slightly at center axis, not plates. Heads simply stick to plates. If doing it quickly, all dust trapped inside will be filtered at air filter inside disk an should not damage heads and data.

Comment: If drive is not spinning then most common issue is an electrical problem. Opening the drive in this case will not help and is risky. If you want to try this on your own drives, fine by me, but I consider it bad practice recommending it to others.

Comment: This is VERY bad advice. Heads sit less than the diameter of a human hair's height above the platter. You need a very specialized environment to prevent permanent and irrecoverable damage to the drive opening it up. Don't do this.